# Kafka Connect on EKS Running into NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS Error

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to run Kafka Connect on EKS using the Confluent image. The Kafka Connect cluster refers to an MSK cluster.
When the Kubernetes pods are created, I see these logs printed over and over.

`[2022-01-07 21:55:12,337] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-3] Got error produce response with correlation id 6695 on topic-partition _connect-configs-0, retrying (2147476960 attempts left). Error: NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)`

Below is my kustomize configuration:

```
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: $APP_NAME
  replicas: 3
template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: $APP_NAME
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: $APP_NAME
          image: $APP_NAME-image
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort:  8083
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "500m"
              memory: 1000Mi
            limits:
              cpu: "1"
              memory: 3000Mi
          env:
            - name: CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR
              value: "3"
            - name: CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR
              value: "3"
            - name: CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR
              value: "3"
...
```

Is there some other configuration to be updated to get rid of these warning messages?

Comment: You appear to not have enough in-sync replicas (https://towardsdatascience.com/10-configs-to-make-your-kafka-producer-more-resilient-ec6903c63e3f). I'd work through each of the suggestions in that article.

Comment: I do have 3 partitions for internal Connect topics.

Comment: Partitions are not the same as replicas. How many broker pods do you have running?

Comment: Sorry I didn't type it right. I meant to say I had set it to 3 replicas and 2 insync replicas. I had to reassign partitions for it work. Thanks! :)

Comment: One curious point is that when I try to run the docker run command for the same setup, I get the following exception:

`Topic '_connect-configs' supplied via the 'config.storage.topic' property is required to have a single partition in order to guarantee consistency of connector configurations, but found 3 partitions.` Any idea why this could be?

Comment: If you didn't manually create the topic, it will automatically be created with 1 partition. Sounds like this is not the case, and thus why you get the warning

Comment: By the way, the Strimzi Kafka Operator has a CRD for KafkaConnect, so you can simplify the need for a Deployment spec (and a LoadBalancer) using the Confluent images

Comment: @JamesMcPherson Please consider posting this as answer since it's correct and helped OP to resolve the question.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, does the Strimzi KafkaConnect operator also have mirror maker 2 built in?
If not, is there a reference that you could share to setup MirrorMaker2 alongside MSK?

Comment: MirrorMaker2 is built-into Kafka Connect, so it's just another `connector.class` you can set in the config. But yes, https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/overview.html#configuration-points-topic_str And I believe it should work with any Kafka Cluster, not just one hosted in k8s

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I setup KafkaConnect cluster on the destination cluster with config:
```{
  "name": "mirror-maker-test-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector",
    "topics": "topic_to_mirror",
    "source.cluster.alias": "dev-cluster",
    "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "source.server.list",
    "enabled": "true",
    "target.cluster.alias": "mirrormaker-test-dev",
    "name": "mirror-maker-test-connector",
    "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "dest.server.list"
  }
}```
I still see task list empty.

Comment: @OneCricketeer - I have posted my issue with mirror maker 2 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70673874/mirror-maker2-not-able-to-connect-to-target-cluster-broker