# Mirror Maker2 not able to connect to target cluster broker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, aws-msk, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I have two Kafka clusters on AWS MSK (in same environment and region). I have a KafkaConnect cluster setup on the destination cluster and have setup a mirror maker connector to run. The submission of the connector is fine and there are no errors.

When I try to check status of the connector, it says, RUNNING:
`{"name":"mirror-maker-test-connector","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"<ip>:<port>"},"tasks":[task_list],"type":"source"}`

I see the following exception:

```
[2022-01-12 19:46:33,772] DEBUG [Producer clientId=connector-producer-mirror-maker-test-connector-0] Connection with b-2.<broker_ip> disconnected (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:120)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:328)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2022-01-12 19:46:33,773] DEBUG [Producer clientId=connector-producer-mirror-maker-test-connector-0] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-01-12 19:46:33,773] WARN [Producer clientId=connector-producer-mirror-maker-test-connector-0] Bootstrap broker b-2.<broker_ip>:9094 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

I am able to connect to the specified broker with `netcat` from within the Kafka Connect k8s pod.

Anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Try installing and using `kcat -L` rather than a direct netcat connection, which doesn't verify that the `advertised.listeners` configured on the cluster are correct

Comment: I got it to work - had to add SSL properties for both consumer and producer when submitting the Mirror Maker connector.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work - had to add SSL properties for both consumer and producer when submitting the Mirror Maker connector.

```
"target.cluster.security.protocol": "SSL", 
"target.cluster.ssl.truststore.location":"<certs_path>",
"target.cluster.ssl.truststore.password": "<password>"
"source.cluster.security.protocol": "SSL",
"source.cluster.ssl.truststore.location": "<certs_path>",
"source.cluster.ssl.truststore.password": "<password>"
```